# How do make new website using MEAN stack application in Windows 10 home?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Some more days ago I installed MEAN stack application on my system, but I haven't any idea for MEAN stack application. How do make a new website using this MEAN stack application in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is watch some tutorial videos on how to make an AngularJS website on youtube and follow along with what they do. This will give you a basic understanding of how a AngularJS website works. Then I would probably suggest googling for an open source meanJS site. I would probably use something like https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-stack-registration-login-example set it up on my own server and play around with it. Learn what everything does and how it does it. Then as you deconstruct the site and learn, start to work on your own.

Comment: Yes! I have checked .This link is very useful.Thanks for your support.